# Чем можно заменить TelegramContext.replyOrEdit() в новой версии Telegraf?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

Есть сцена, в которой я использую `context.editMessageText()`. Но при вызове сцены командой по понятным причинам ничего не происходит. `context.reply` мне не подходит, а `replyOrEdit` сейчас не работает. Чем можно заменить `TelegramContext.replyOrEdit()` в новой версии Telegram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопавшись в файлах старой версии Telegraf, я нашел решение.

```
context[context.updateType == "callback_query" ? "editMessageText" : "reply"](args)
```

ПС. подсмотрел я это в проекте у другого разработчика. Подозреваю, что в оригинальном пакете метода replyOrEdit не существует